# Can not Debug on Visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, debugging, iis-express

Asp.net MVC project, on Visual Studio , Hosted on Azure, Connected with Microsoft Dynamics CRM,
Downloaded from SourceSafe using Visual Studio 2019
=> Project is Not using Entity Framework but connected CRM Datasource
=> Angular and  Gulp in the project

1. Built and rebuilt: working fine
2. Debug: I cant not debug the project using IIS Express
3. Not hitting any Breakpoints on the C# code

[image]

Diagnostic tool

[image]

Local host opening up a blower with the port number but it is showing

the message Below
[image]

Comment: and you have no idea where that text is coming from?

Comment: People often use Chrome developer tools to learn more about each HTTP requests/responses and tell where some message comes from. That's what exactly you should do now.